# Spacemacs / Mac

Tags: spacemacs, osx

I have installed Emacs (emacs-plus) via Homebrew on my Mac.

My problem is that if I in the Finder chooses "open with" -> Emacs, Emacs open all right, but its not always the right file that is opened! Sometimes it's the right file, sometimes it's a file i have edited sometimes in the past.

What could be wrong? Any hint to debugging this problem?

Extra info:

- The wrong file that's opened is typically the last i have edited/closed.
- The correct file is not opened in any buffers (before or after).
- Second time i choose "open with", the correct file is opened.
- After restart of Emacs, the problem disappears for some time.

Comment: Check the `buffer-list` to see if your file is open, but not being displayed.  `M-x list-buffers` or `C-x C-b`.  I assume you have an open Emacs in the background and your concern is that the file being opened in Finder is not being displayed, but it may in fact be open somewhere in Emacs.  You may also wish to try a plain old Emacs built `--with-ns` (for OSX) without the Homebrew stuff and see if everything works as expected:  https://emacsformacosx.com/  Adding a Homebrew to the equation can complicate the diagnosis.  Select the proper Emacs application when using `open-with`:  **Other...**.

Comment: If you haven't rebooted your computer in the last century, please reboot.  You would be surprised how many people never reboot their Mac.  Also, restart Emacs please.  And, you might as well disable all the `spacemacs` stuff to eliminate that from part of the equation when diagnosing the problem -- no need to complicate the diagnosis by enabling `spacemacs`.  In a nutshell, you want to try things with zero user-configuration -- aka **Emacs -Q**  If everything works okay with zero user-configuration, then recursively bisect your customizations by commenting sutff out and restarting Emacs.